# TouchableHighlight onPress doesnt work

Tags: react-native

My function `onPress`return `undefined is not a object`

This is my code :

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Image, Platform, StatusBar, ListView, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {
    Container,
    Content,
    Text,
    Icon,
    View,
    Left,
    Right,
    Header,
    Body,
    Title,
    Animated

} from 'native-base';

import styles from './styles';


class Championnat extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
                {slug : 'team', name : 'Liqgue1'},
                {slug : 'worldcup', name : 'Coupe du monde'},
            ]),
        };
    }

    pressRow(data) {

        console.log(data);

    }

    renderRow(data){
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> this.pressRow(data)}>
                <View style={styles.lstView}>
                    <Image style={styles.lstPicto} />
                    <Text style={styles.lstText}>{data.name}</Text>
                    <Icon name="angle-right" right style={styles.lstIcon} />
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>

        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container style={styles.container}>

                <Header style={styles.header}>
                    <Left>
                        <Button transparent onPress={() => Actions.pop()}>
                            <Icon active name="angle-left"/>
                        </Button>
                    </Left>
                    <Body>
                        <Title>Choisir un championnat</Title>
                    </Body>
                    <Right></Right>
                </Header>

                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <ListView

                        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                        renderRow = {this.renderRow.bind(this)}

                    ></ListView>
                </View>

            </Container>

        )
    }
}

export default connect()(Championnat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `constructor` you need to `bind()` your function, or use arrow functions.

```
constructor() {
  // your code
  this.pressRow = this.pressRow.bind(this);
}
```

Otherwise, declare your function as an arrow function.

```
pressRow = (data) => {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your suggeste, but it doesnt work ... Same pb

Answer (score 0):

change `renderRow(data)` as arrow function like below snippet

```
renderRow = (data) => {
  // your logic
}
```

and make sure you pressRow function should be arrow function

```
pressRow = (data) => {
           console.log(data);
}
```

Hope this will work. :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer,

Comment: can you please give me more info on your question. can we have entire component code snippet. it would be helpful to find issue

Comment: Yes i've post it

Comment: Hi. user flatList instead of listview. it will be more easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

This is my screen when i `tape` on `TouchableHighlight`. The pb exist only on `TouchableHighlight` if i change `TouchableHighlight` for `Button`, there is no pb. 
But on offical doc (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html), react ask to use `TouchableHighlight` on listView

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this one.. it should work.. when you render a listView, each of you data belong to one unique ID..

```js
pressRow(event) {
  console.log(event);
}

renderRow(data, rowID){
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight key={rowID} onPress={()=> this.pressRow(rowID)}>
    <View style={styles.lstView}>
        <Image style={styles.lstPicto} />
        <Text style={styles.lstText}>{data.name}</Text>
        <Icon name="angle-right" right style={styles.lstIcon} />
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>

        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my entire code : 
In renderRow, if i comment `Button` an decomment `TouchableHighlight` it doesn't work, if i comment `TouchableHighlight` and decomment `Button`, it'work's.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Image, Platform, StatusBar, ListView, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {
    Container,
    Content,
    Text,
    Item,
    Input,
    Button,
    Icon,
    View,
    Left,
    Right,
    Header,
    Body,
    Title,
    Spinner,
    Animated

} from 'native-base';

import styles from './styles';
import * as competition from '../../../services/competition';


class ContentLoaded extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>Hello {this.props.name}!</Text>
        );
    }
}

class Competition extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.pressRow = this.pressRow.bind(this);


        this.state = {
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
                rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
            }),
            loaded: false,
        };

        this.fetchData();


    }

    /**
     * Cherche les competitions
     */
    fetchData = function() {

        competition.getAll()
            .then((data) => {

                console.log(data);

                this.setState({
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data),
                    loaded: true,
                });

            })
            .catch((exception) => {

                console.log('competition controller 47', exception);

            });

    }

    /**
     * Click sur une competiotn
     * @param data
     */
    pressRow = (data, rowId) => {

        console.log(data);
        console.log(rowId);


    }

    /**
     * render d'une ligne
     * @param data
     * @returns {XML}
     */
    renderRow(data, rowId){
        return (
            //<TouchableHighlight key={rowID} style={styles.lstView} onPress={()=> this.pressRow(rowId)}>

                <Button style={styles.lstView} onPress={()=> this.pressRow(data, rowId)}>
                    <Image style={styles.lstPicto} />
                    <Text style={styles.lstText}>{data.name}</Text>
                    <Icon name="angle-right" right style={styles.lstIcon} />
                </Button>

            //</TouchableHighlight>

        )
    }

    /**
     * Affichage conditionnek
     * @returns {XML}
     * @constructor
     */
    ContentLoaded () {

        if (!this.state.loaded) {
            return <Text>
                Loading movies...
            </Text>
        }

        return  <ListView

            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow = {this.renderRow.bind(this)}

        ></ListView>


    }

    /**
     * Render
     * @returns {XML}
     */
    render() {

        return (
            <Container style={styles.container}>

                <Header style={styles.header}>
                    <Left>
                        <Button transparent onPress={() => Actions.pop()}>
                            <Icon active name="angle-left"/>
                        </Button>
                    </Left>
                    <Body>
                        <Title>Choisir un championnat</Title>
                    </Body>
                    <Right></Right>
                </Header>

                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    {!this.state.loaded ? (
                        <Spinner size="small" color="#000000" />
                    ) : (
                        <ListView

                            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                            renderRow = {this.renderRow.bind(this)}

                        ></ListView>
                    )}
                </View>

            </Container>

        )
    }
}

export default connect()(Competition);
```

Comment: you pressRow need to received two argument but inside TouchableHighlight you also send rowId.. try copy this.pressRow(data, rowId) inside Button onPress...

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Image, Platform, StatusBar, ListView, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {
    Container,
    Content,
    Text,
    Icon,
    View,
    Left,
    Right,
    Header,
    Body,
    Title,
    Animated

} from 'native-base';

import styles from './styles';


class Championnat extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
                {slug : 'team', name : 'Liqgue1'},
                {slug : 'worldcup', name : 'Coupe du monde'},
            ]),
        };
    }

    pressRow(data) {

        console.log(data);

    }

    renderRow(data){
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> this.pressRow(data)}>
                <View style={styles.lstView}>
                    <Image style={styles.lstPicto} />
                    <Text style={styles.lstText}>{data.name}</Text>
                    <Icon name="angle-right" right style={styles.lstIcon} />
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>

        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container style={styles.container}>

                <Header style={styles.header}>
                    <Left>
                        <Button transparent onPress={() => Actions.pop()}>
                            <Icon active name="angle-left"/>
                        </Button>
                    </Left>
                    <Body>
                        <Title>Choisir un championnat</Title>
                    </Body>
                    <Right></Right>
                </Header>

                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <ListView

                        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                        renderRow = {this.renderRow.bind(this)}

                    ></ListView>
                </View>

            </Container>

        )
    }
}

export default connect()(Championnat);
```